# Redirect 301 except when a string is present in url with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I would like to redirect a subdirectory to a subdomain, but i have to maintenance the endpoints for sitemaps.

What I need is:

```
Redirect 301 /ru/ https://ru.mydomain.com
#Exclude *sitemap*
```

This kind of urls can't be redirected:

```
https://www.mydomain/ru/sitemap.xml
https://www.mydomain/ru/sitemap.1.xml
https://www.mydomain/ru/sitemap.3.xml
https://www.mydomain/ru/sitemap_ru.xml
```

All have sitemap string and i need no be redirected when sitemap word is in url.
Hope can help me, as i take many time trying to fix it without luck.

I need like:

```
{if *sitemap* is not present}
Redirect 301 /ru/ https://ru.mydomain.com
{/if}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the apache version?

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for you. If the URL on your website (www.mydomain) starts with /ru but not with /ru/sitemap... we redirect (301) to https://ru.mydomain.com/ but without the /ru in the path. e.g. https://www.mydomain/ru/news goes to https://ru.mydomain.com/news

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?ru(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?ru/sitemap.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?ru(/(.*))?$ https://ru.mydomain.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

The NC Flag means that this is case insensitive.
You need [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) installed end enabled!